# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Not yet implemented

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am fetching some problem when I trying to print Arabic letter by using DirectPrint bean. This is a pjc. English fonts are printed fine, but when I want to print Arabic there is showing a exception below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Not yet implemented
at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.drawString(PDType0Font.java:75)
at org.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.showCharacter(PageDrawer.java:160)
at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.showString(PDFStreamEngine.java:409)
at org.pdfbox.util.operator.ShowTextGlyph.process(ShowTextGlyph.java:80)
at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:452)
at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:174)
at org.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:104)
at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.print(PDPage.java:741)
at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.printPage(RasterPrinterJob.java:1936)
at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1431)
at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1247)
at dsd.printing.DirectPrint.main(DirectPrint.java:842)
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: use the 2.0 version. Read the migration guide first.

Comment: thanks, solve the issue, i am using pdfbox2.0.RC3.jar and now its working

Comment: 2.0 has been released friday, it should be available for maven: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of PDFBox you are using? What I see from here:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Not yet implemented
at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.drawString(PDType0Font.java:75)
```

That it says **`PDType0Font`** class and **`drawString`** method straightly throws **'Not yet implemented'** exception but i.e. if I check one of the latest version (i.e. 1.8.10) I can see the method implemented: [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/1.8.10/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDSimpleFont.java#PDSimpleFont.drawString%28java.lang.String%2Cint[]%2Cjava.awt.Graphics%2Cfloat%2Cjava.awt.geom.AffineTransform%2Cfloat%2Cfloat%29)

If I would be I would try to change the version of pdfbox library and try again.

*EDIT: Thanks to Tilman, latest version info from his comment: 2.0 has been released friday, it should be available for maven: mvnrepository.com/artifact*/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox

Comment: i am using pdfbox0.7.3

Comment: @bdmsys 0.7.3 is 10 years old.

Comment: thanks, solve the issue, i am using pdfbox2.0.RC3.jar and now its working

Comment: @HRgiger your answer didn't suggest 2.0. But feel free to edit it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the Arabic characters are not implemented to be converted by the `pdfbox` library you're using.